# I can't store category_id on table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I cannot get category_id when I created a topic. Here are my codes and mysql. I think I have a problem in store method on forum controller.

[mysql pro screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlKkq.png)

Topic create page

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <h1>トピック</h1>
    <hr>
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'forums']) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('title', 'タイトル:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('body', '本文:') !!}
            {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('category', 'カテゴリー:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('category', $categories,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('送信',['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
        </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

@stop
```

forums controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Topic;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class ForumsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $topics = Topic::latest()->get();
       return view('forums.index',compact('categories','topics'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
      $categories = Category::lists('title', 'id');
       return view('forums.create', compact('categories'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      Auth::user()->topics()->save(new Topic($request->all()));



       // flash()->success('投稿しました','success');

       // return redirect('forums');
    }
}
```

Category model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title'
        ];

    public function topics()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Topic');
    }
}
```

Topic model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class topic extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'body'
        ];

    public function category()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\category');
    }

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add category_id to the topic's Model fillable array like this

```
 protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'body',
     'category_id'
    ];
```

Comment: it did not work,but thanks for your help.much appreciated

Comment: change this  Form::select('category', $categories,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) to  Form::select('category_id', $categories,null, ['class' => 'form-control'])

Comment: you are using category in your forms whiles the field in your database is category_id. so to use mass assigment you have to change the category to category_id in your form